# Starting Oracle as a service inside the docker container

Tags: oracle, docker

I build and run Oracle Database with [this dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile) that starts the Oracle instance with the command at the last line of the dockerfile.

```
CMD exec $ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE
```

The Oracle instance works, I am able to connect to it with Oracle SQL Developer, but I am unable to do

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trail=db SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

, for example, and get the following errors:

```
ORA-65040: operation not allowed from within a pluggable database
65040. 00000 -  "operation not allowed from within a pluggable database"
*Cause:    An operation was attempted that can only be performed in the root
       container.
*Action:   Switch to the root container to perform the operation.
```

So, as far as I see I need to start something like sqlplus locally in the docker container and then probably restart the instance with SHUTDOWN and STARTUP commands.

What is the easiest way to do this in the container I have? Should I make Oracle start as a service inside the docker container? Is it the best alternative? (At least the service will start when the container is run and I will be able to use bash inside the container, but this requires modification and rebuilding the dockerfile). I am not an expert in linux/docker/oracle and I need to know if I am going to the right direction or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect to the database from sqldeveloper you will properly get connected to the PDB (Pluggable database) so you need to change the current container (DB) to the main container

```
alter session set container = CDB;
```

or some thing like that.

You can also create the database as a non-CDB traditional database to avoid  the Pluggable DB fuzz. Just change the response file used to create the DB.

Alternative do it in sqlplus:

Access the container:

```
docker exec -it <your container-id/name> /bin/bash
cd /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhome_1/bin
./sqlplus sys/<your syspwd> as sysdba
```

For some reason the ORACLE_SID is sometime missing and will give you a wierd

```
ORA-12162 TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

so when in the container please verify and evt. set it before accessing the DB.

```
env
export ORACLE_SID=<your sid>
```

Comment: Tried alter session set container = 'CDB';, but got ORA-65015: missing or invalid container name

Comment: Try without quotes, I've skipped the pluggable stuff in my own environment so I cant test it.

Comment: Without quotes I got: ORA-65011: Pluggable database CDB does not exist.

Comment: What is you db version 12c, 18c? For 18.1+ there seems to be a bug BUG:28558287 - ORA-65011: PLUGGABLE DATABASE DOES NOT EXIST.
--- Solution, restart DB ---

Comment: my db version is 18c

Comment: my db version is 18c, "Oracle Database 18c Standard Edition 2 Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0"

Comment: Can you try the alternative I give in my edit to the answer? There you should get to the CDB directly. OR try the restart workaround described in the bug.

Comment: I did 'sudo docker exec -it oracle18se /bin/bash' (it is a very good idea) and started './sqlplus sys as sysdba' but got 'ERROR: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified'

Comment: looks like I need 'set ORACLE_SID=database name'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189896/discussion-between-f-madsen-and-alexey-starinsky).